# jQuery drop down - .click event works on <a> tag but not on <span> inside <a>

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, onclick

I found a little JSFiddle to create a simple drop down menu - see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mWZa/100/)

This works great as long as the trigger `<a href="#language" class="dropdown-toggle">English</a>` doesn't contain anything inside the a tag - but I have FontAwesome glyphs as well as text inside spans like this:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-gift"></i> <span>Store</span>
</a>
```

In this instance, the menu still gets triggered but not if you directly click a glyph or text - does anyone know how to correct this behavior?

I've only started learning jQuery this week so don't full understand everything that's going on sorry - any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's a security feature of most browsers. Also, don't put an anchor tag around an <li>. It's not valid XHTML.

Comment: @Juann Strauss - Thanks for that but I thought it was acceptable in HTML5 (if it isn't, it should be): http://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or You can add :

```
    if ( $this.hasClass( opts.toggle ) || $this.parent().hasClass(opts.toggle))
```

instead of

```
if ( $this.hasClass( opts.toggle )
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6mWZa/102/

Comment: Thanks heaps for the answers - because I'm learning, does the other answer (@A. Wolf) make another trip into the DOM using ```.find``` Where as your answer doesn't? Am I reading that right?

Comment: @CMSCSS `$this.parent()` will make an other 'trip' to the DOM too

Comment: @A. Wolf Sorry, I'm still learning - isn't ```$this``` cached with ```var $this = $(e.target);``` Or does ```.parent``` force jQuery to go back to the DOM?

Comment: @CMSCSS parent() is a transversal method. When caching an element, you are not caching all its ancestors. But anyway, this doesn't make any difference if you don't have thousand elements.

Comment: After more testing this option works best because the drop down doesn't collapse if an item inside the drop down is clicked (like a search form or shopping cart for instance)

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
var $this = $(e.target);
```

By:

```
var $this = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-toggle');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6mWZa/101/)

Comment: Actually I think this one is slightly better (yes compared to image optimisation it's a negligible performance difference) but I like grabbing all the elements at the same time when they're cached. Thanks heaps for the answers and your time, Cheers